# does anyone knows how to make similar Materials to this? (Blue marble)

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, uv, objects

i found this Material   online but i can't make similar one can anyone help ? [image]

Comment: Hi. What have you got so far and where, *specifically*, are you getting stuck? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you should make your title a little bit more explicit and tell what kind of object or texture it is

Answer (score 4):

Here. I played around for a while and made this. I'm not sure it's what you're looking for, but it's SOMEWHAT similar. At least you can see how some things are done and maybe play with it to make it more to your liking.

**EDIT** - here is the full description of the thought process I used to achieve this result. I have also added an updated .blend file which reflects some changes I made .

First off,  to start,  I took the "generated" vector from a texture coordinate, as this is the convention when making procedural textures.

The main idea was that the planet in your image seems to have both surface and atmospheric "ripples". There are also "bright spots" in the atmosphere that have a wispy look that is also somewhat rippled. To get the ripple shape for all of these, I used noise textures.

For the "atmospheric spots" As you can see from the graph,  I took a noise texture and subtracted another noise texture with a slightly larger scale (smaller pattern) to get some more "believable" and "disruptive" distortion. However, the resulting combination was too "noisy", so I added the white values from yet another noise texture, scaled slightly higher again to isolate some "spots".

[image: Spots]

From here, I turned this "spot" image into to 2 different color graphs - one emission based and the other plain color, which I mainly used to highlight the spots and darken the planet, which results in somewhat of an "atmospheric subsurface), especially when I also combined the emission map with the noise texture I used for the normal (more on this later) to cause certain parts of the emission to shine, and others to be suppressed.

[image: ColorMapSpot]

With regards to the normal, I wanted something rippled and distorted to reflect the light at different intensities through the emission. For this I used a noise texture scaled up substantially to make very small ripples, which I then put thorough a bright/contrast node to lessen the difference between light and dark on the map - giving a smoother more subtle appearance to the normal (more appropriate for an atmosphere than for ground). I also used a math node to  subtract some value from the image to make it slightly darker so it would shine a bit when used as a roughness map.

[image: NormalRough]

For the "inner" planet, I wanted it to seem mountainous with a rich topography, so I took the values from the normal map noise and used it as a mix factor between light and dark (high and low) areas of the planet. I then combined this with a slightly blued gradient texture to help give that "planetary" spherical look.

[image: InnerPlanet]

I then used a musgrave texture with the detail turned up to get some white values that look like spotty clouds. I then added this to my planetary color (non emission), which darkened the whole thing (to make it stand out as a g"ground" when compared with the emissive atmosphere), but also added those spotty cloud "whites" to the mix.

[image: Musgrave]

I then started using my color maps as the values for emission shaders in order to get different levels of "glow" for the different layers.

[image: Emissions]

I also added the light values from a fresnel (combined with emission is great for "atmospheric glow"), which is influenced by the normal 0 this helped preserve the "rippled" atmosphere.

[image: Fresnel]

Finally I combined all the maps together, using the fresnel as the factor for the final mix. I then turned on bloom to make it glow, and turned up the bloom intensity so I could get a bigger glow without washing out the colors (as opposed to increasing the emissions strength).

The final result is below:

[image: FINAL]

And here is the .blend file for those interested in playing around with it.

File is here -----  [image]

Comment: oh thanks man for taking time to make this :)

Comment: No problem. It's not perfect - maybe kinda hackish in some areas. I kind of started falling asleep as I was making it and cut some corners just to get it done. I'll give a re-look in the morning and see if I can make it better.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for taking the time to answer. BSE is more of knowledge database than a library of ready-made downloadable solutions. Answers should thoroughly described the process in the answer body. Could you explaining the used workflow and illustrate the node setup so users don't have to download the file to understand?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a full description, along with an improved .blend file.

Comment: thanks man again for helping and taking time to help me that is an amazing work :)

Answer (score 4):

I've also given a try (needs to be improved). To sum it up it's like a stack of layers: one with blue spots, one with bright spots, one with glossiness, and finally 2 *Layer Weight* nodes to add *Emission* and *Transparency* on the circumference.

[image]
[image]

Another solution, this time you have 2 balls, a big glassy one, with *Layer Weight* and some bright spots, containing a smaller one, with the blue matter. It won't change a lot except if you make the sphere rotating, in that case you'll see depth.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Hey, moonboots, that's really good! I didn't even think to use layer weights - I guess that's the downside of attempting to produce a shader at 5:30 AM. Oh well, now I'm gonna look at your graph and steal your ideas and there's nothing you can do about it, Ha Ha Ha! - JK ;)

Comment: thanks, no problem, I'm sure it can be improved  ;)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Upvoting is another way to show appreciation for a good answer.

Comment: actually I'm not even sure what kind of object it is, it looks like there are 2 layers, it should be done with 2 balls

Comment: @batFINGER - Done! I was too busy thinking of a cheeky compliment, that I forgot at first.

Comment: Wow guys thanks for help :) i can't believe that people would help me to that extend thanks again

Comment: Hello, I hope you'll understand my node setup, it was too hard to explain in details, if you don't get something don't hesitate to ask, and again I think it's really improvable  ;)